# Why my fur texture only looks right on eevee render?

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

I was ready to render this image but deleted some part from the hat that now the EEVEE looks right, but when I change to Cycles the fur part looks black.

Does anyone know what I can do this solve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the value for Hair > Hair Shape Type in render settings of Eevee? Is it set to *Strip*?